# Is there a SEDE query that finds all questions that I asked and answered myself?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I'm looking for a particular question that I answered myself, because I want to find a meta-discussion in the comments about whether that's okay (spoiler: [it is](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)).

Has anyone written a query that will find those questions for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I have done that [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/626221?UserId=3476191). (thanks [NobodyNada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3476191/nobodynada) for self-answering that question and [Raw N](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/626221/is-there-a-sede-query-that-finds-all-questions-that-i-asked-and-answered-myself?UserId=1593881) and [TylerH](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/626221/is-there-a-sede-query-that-finds-all-questions-that-i-asked-and-answered-myself?UserId=2756409))

I join here the posts table with itself as it holds both questions and answers. The parentid on an answer act as the foreignkey for the question it belongs to. To select posts that belong to a specific user we limit the results to a specific owneruserid. As you're only interested in self-answers we apply that condition to both questions and answers.

```sql
select q.id as [Post Link]
from posts q 
inner join posts a on a.parentid = q.id
where q.owneruserid = ##userid##
and a.owneruserid  = ##userid##
```

You can switch the query to any site (main or meta) and enter your userid for that specific site.

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday.